# Is a function without input/output a procedure?

Tags: c++, c, function, terminology, procedure

I read many many articles about difference between `function` and `procedure` but there is something I'm in doubt about.

Do we call following statement a `function` or a `procedure` in terminology?

```
void f() { return; }
```

Some articles says function returns value but procedure does not.

Some other article says if a function returns one value called `function` but if it returns more than one value it called `procedure`.

Comment: It really depends on the language, and I don't think procedure is a very useful term in either C or C++.

Comment: In C and C-like languages there are no procedures, only functions.

Comment: C++ uses the term 'function' regardless of whether it returns anything or not.  It also doesn't use the term `method` for member functions. That said, I think that if you used those terms it wouldn't cause confusion - just don't expect them to be used by others.

Comment: @BennoZeeman I've read that thread before. I think my question is different

Comment: Where did you find the distinction in the last paragraph? It sounds very odd.

Comment: @molbdnilo http://www.geekinterview.com/question_details/4662

Comment: @HamedKamrava That's a "PL/SQL" question (and answer). Programming terminology is often very language-specific.

Comment: @HamedKamrava [It does](http://stackoverflow.com/a/721132/2703418). A few people mention the language specificness of this terminology. A procedure is just a function C. The distinction is gone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the standard terminology of C and C++, no. It's a function whether or not it returns anything, or even if it doesn't return.

In more general computing vocabulary, and the terminology of other programming languages, it might be called a "procedure" or a "subroutine" (and perhaps a few other terms) if it doesn't return a value.

Answer (score 1):

A procedure is a function that do not return a result!

Comment: I agree and with all the posts that point out that C and C++ both only refer to functions not procedures.

Many authors tend to differentiate that functions return values and procedures have side-effects.

I think that distinction is consistent with the way 'function' is normally used in mathematics and 'procedure' as a set of instructions to perform an action. Think of (say) a building evacuation procedure.

I'm not so sure the distinction is hugely useful in programming as many candidates have side-effects and return values. What do we call them?

Comment: What about a function which sometimes returns a result? (j/k)

Comment: are you talking about idempotent functions Mr. Dany Allen?

Answer (score 1):

There is no such term as procedure in C and C++ languages. So relative to C and C++ languages your question has no sense. In any other languages the definition of the term procedure can vary.

In C and C++ statement

```
void f() { return; }
```

is a **function** definition.

Comment: I know there is no such term as procedure in C/C++. But I mean do we call it `function` or `procedure` in concept ?

Comment: @Hamed Kamrava As there is no such a concept as procedure in C/C++ then there is no sense to speak about this term in the frames of C/C++. As I wrote in my posty the concept can vary in other languages where it is defined.

Answer (score 1):

As Mike annd Grzegorz says, from C Standard point of view there is no difference, but the **function** term is used by convention.

In other programming language (e.g. basic) that distinction is commonly used depending if return or not a value that function.

**As final note:** in the *C Programming Language* book (official C programming language book) from Dennis Ritchie (C creator) the term **function** is used independently if returns or not a value and that's one of the reason that the term is used indistinctly.

Comment: No, the official C language document is ISO/IEC 9899. _The C Programming Language_ by **Kernighan** and Ritchie is not official, although influential.

Comment: Well, maybe I've been ambiguous. When I said that is the official C programming language book I'm referring that is the de facto standard for learn C, and not a specification or C Language document.

Answer (score 0):

From the C Standard point of view there is no distinction between functions and procedures (like in e.g. Pascal) or subroutines (like in e.g. Fortran). Both types (i.e. returning `void` and non-`void`) are simply named as functions. I believe that C++ just follows this way.

Answer (score 0):

There are various terminologies that means the same in various different languages. Like function used in structured language like c, Method's used in java, procedure, function both used in Scala.

In reality, Procedure is a function really but that doesn't return anything and in C we still refer to it as function.