# Which one is better, 'double pointer' or 'returning pointer' in C?

Tags: c, pointers

Belows are image of STACK that i made to show two methods of assignment.
Left one, where return 'indexIndicator' from Find() to main() after procedure of Find() is over. 
Light one is pointer of pointer(double pointer). 
I know that both work well, but i want to know which one is preferred and why. Thanks 
[image]

Comment: Please use code to describe code, not hard-to-understand images.

Comment: The images are a nice touch though.

Comment: Lemme get this straight. You're asking which of `void find(void* key, void** val)` and `void* find(void* key)` is preferable? The answer is "it depends". I personally favour `int find(void* key, void** val)`, since then `find` can be used both as an _is-present_ test (By passing a `NULL` as the second argument) and as an actual _find_, plus it's consistent with a `int del(void* key, void** delVal)`, where I _don't_ want the user to be able to simply chuck away dynamically-allocated memory. On the other hand the 2nd variant lets you do stuff like `find(key)->pointer.madness`.

Comment: Please provide some code, I need to understand, on the left will indexes be a pointer to the first pointer in Heap or will indexes point to the same address as the first element in heap points to?

Comment: irrelevant to your question bu how did you generate this neat diagram?

Comment: @barej just power point :)

Answer (score 2):

Well in general, if your function calculates some value you should then use a return; and if your function need to modifies something, you should pass it as a parameter. This rule makes the code easier to read and understand. It is not always easy to follow such a rule, especially when you need to return a bunch of values... Anyway, the semantic of your function should help you.

- A `find()` function generally return the value found, `pElement = find(list,criterion);` for example.
- A `set()` function generally takes as parameter the value to be
  modified, `set(&element);`

Comment: Sorry, but hard to understand.. T_T

Comment: Maybe this topic will help you more ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/721090/what-is-the-difference-between-a-function-and-a-procedure `find` is a function (in mathematical sense) and `set` a procedure (a pure computer programming concept). A math function is generally implemented as a C-function returning a value, and a procedure is implemented as a C-function that takes pointers as arguments so that it can modify them.