# Explicitly call return even if nothing is expected to be returned?

Tags: python

I was wondering if there is (or is not) a reason to call `return` after a function is done but no value is expected to be returned. Is there a best practice or does it just not matter?

For example:

```
def print_something(arg):
    print(arg)
    return
```

The last instruction `return` of function `print_something`. Should it be there or should it not? Does it just add unessecary instructions to executed application? Or is there just no point in thinking about it?

Comment: I think you should start with some basics: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/721090/what-is-the-difference-between-a-function-and-a-procedure

Comment: Advice noted. I just use "function" for everything and never thought about the naming.

Comment: In your exampe it does not make sense. But it would, if you for exampe have a condition which was met and you don't want to execute the rest of the function

Comment: @ap0 agreed, there is a distinction formally but they are also equivalent in python since there is `None`.

Answer (score 1):

If a function intends to perform some action and not return anything then it is customary to not include the return statement, even as `None` is returned:

```
def print_something(arg):
    print(arg)
```

or if `return` is required

```
def print_something(arg):
    if arg == 1:
        return
    print(arg)
```

However it is better practice to write out `return None` when a function can return `None` in some cases and other types in others as it is clearer what's going on:

```
def increment(arg):
    if arg is None:
        return None  # instead of just return
    return arg + 1
```