# Error "AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'append'"

Tags: python

I saw a lot of questions about the same error, but I didn't find anyone that seems to be about the same thing.

A part (that seems relevant to me) of my code is:

```
falta = [0]
x = 0
o = 0
aux = a
while a in range(aux, len(repetido)):
    print("a %s" %a)
    x = 0
    while int(repetido[a].academia) != int(vetor[x].academia):
        print("repetido %s" % repetido[a].academia)
        print("vetor %s" %vetor[x].academia)
        x = x + 1
        if a == aux:
            falta[0] = int(vetor[x].inscricao)
            print("este eh o primeiro falta: %s" %falta[0])
        else:
            falta.append(int(vetor[x].inscricao))
        falta = random.shuffle(falta)
        a = a + 1
```

I get this error message:

```
File "C:/Users/vivia/PycharmProjects/karate/Teste posicoes repetidas.py", line 60, in posicionaAcademiaIgual

falta.append(int(vetor[x].inscricao))

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'append'
```

I don't use this `falta` list on any other place in the program.
Sorry about my poor English.

Comment: `random.shuffle` is a *procedure* in python parlance; it operates on the argument list in place and returns `None`. This is opposed to a *function*, which performs computations around its arguments, often without mutating them, and returns the result of the computation. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/721090/what-is-the-difference-between-a-function-and-a-procedure)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just making my comment an official answer.

When you perform the assignment `falta = random.shuffle(falta)`, `falta` becomes `None`, since `random.shuffle` operates in place and returns `None`. When you come around on your next iteration, `falta` has become none, and the `AttributeError` is thrown when you call `falta.append`.

Instead of

```
falta = random.shuffle(falta)
```

try

```
random.shuffle(falta)
```

And read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/721090/what-is-the-difference-between-a-function-and-a-procedure).

Comment: Thank you sooo much, that's exatly it! Problem solved!

Answer (score -1):

I guess you are using random from numpy. the ranom.shuffle will return None, it shuffle the list in place. so change

```
falta = random.shuffle(falta)
```

to

```
andom.shuffle(falta)
```